# How to import JS module (.mjs) to QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I followed the example provided in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html):

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import "script.mjs" as MyScript
Item {
  width: 100; height: 100
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
      MyScript.showCalculations(10)
      console.log("Call factorial() from QML:",
        MyScript.factorial(10))
    }
  }
}
  

// script.mjs
import { factorial } from "factorial.mjs"
function showCalculations(value) {
  console.log(
   "Call factorial() from script.js:",
   factorial(value));
}
 

// factorial.mjs
export function factorial(a) {
  a = parseInt(a);
  if (a <= 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return a * factorial(a - 1);
}
```

Running qmlscene on main.qml and mouse click on the window triggers the following error:

```
main.qml:12: TypeError: Property 'showCalculations' of object TypeError: Type error is not a function
```

Expected output: Must calculate factorial twice and print to console

If I fix `script.mjs` by exporting `showCalculations` function like this:

```
export function showCalculations(value) {
```

I get factorial calculated only once, but expected twice. Output is the following:

```
qml: Call factorial() from script.js: 3628800
main.qml:13: TypeError: Property 'factorial' of object TypeError: Type error is not a function
```

I also tried to rename `script.mjs` to `script.js`, but that breaks import factorial.js, so it does not help.

One more issue is that docs state that "Sometimes it is desirable to have the functions made available in the importing context without needing to qualify them. In this case ECMAScript modules and the JavaScript import statement should be used without the `as` qualifier."

I tried:

```
import "script.mjs"
```

But I get error:

```
main.qml:4 Script import requires a qualifier
```

Expected: import must happen without issues and one can call `showCalculations()` and `factorial()` without qualifiers.

I created a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-96902) for it, but it can take long until the guys have a look at it. Maybe someone here knows how to get the exact behavior described in the docs. I need to import an ECMAScript module, not just a JS file.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late (but better than never!), but the solution to your problem is pretty simple.

You need to re-`export` `factorial` in `script.mjs`.

If you want to use the normal `js` extension on the `script` file, then you need to do the import the old way:

```js
.import "factorial.mjs" as F

var factorial = F.factorial
```